# In Minecraft, do clocks still work while in item frames?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do clocks still work when in item frames?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they work correctly in item frames.

From the wiki for [clocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock), emphasis mine:

> The dial can be read from a clock in any of its representations: held in a player's hand, placed in any inventory or crafting grid, **in an item frame**, and even as a dropped item.